# Are there alternative methods to creating an empty array then filling it in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am new to Python but I have a decent amount of experience in Java and C, I am trying to create an array of a certain size then fill it with random numbers but no python tutorials about arrays mention methods about doing this (if I search explicitly about wanting that I get results that is not the problem) so I was wondering if that is considered a bad practice in Python and there are alternative ways to accomplishing what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Python has dynamic memory allocation. Just create whenever needed and use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108478/creating-fixed-length-numpy-array-from-variable-length-lists seems related, since you tagged this with numpy.

Comment: The reason I tagged this with numpy is because I have read that there are no arrays in python by default and importing numpy makes arrays available @chelmertz

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for: You can use generators for filling arrays, like https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html and for random numbers look at  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html

Comment: Python `list` is a general purpose array-like structure that can hold many kinds of objects - numbers, strings, other lists. `numpy` arrays are more specialized, best for holding numbers in multidimensions.

Comment: With numpy it's best to ctreate arrays with the desired values directly.  There are for example functions to make arrays of random numbers.  You can initial an array and assign values, but that's usually slower.

Comment: Start off with a general Python introduction (not numpy for now), to learn the basics. Then, if you still really need the features numpy provides, use it. Just because Python does not come with "arrays" (there is still a module of that name providing them), it does not mean you cannot use the same or similar algorithms as in Java or C, using the available data structures (like lists or dicts).

Comment: @Sergio in python, you would normally use `list` objects where in another language you might use a primitive array, (although, in most real cases in Java you'd use a member of the `List` interface  as well, e.g. `ArrayList`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still to new to comment on @icejoywoo post ^

list are basically arrays for most purposes.

list comprehension is the easiest way to fill an array with lots of things

```
[ returnVal for i in range(10)]
```

any for loop or iterator will work
return value itself can be a function

```
x= [None for i in range(10)]
[None,None..None]

x= [x**2 for i in range(10)]
[0,1,4..81]

y = lambda a: int((a**.5)*100)
x= [y(i) for i in range(10)]
[0, 100, 141, 173, 200, 223, 244, 264, 282, 300]
```

Answer (score 2):

use random or numpy

```py
In [1]: import random

In [2]: [random.random() for i in range(10)]
Out[2]:
[0.8233249954348517,
 0.6215056571076538,
 0.6273288221606772,
 0.12055176228045617,
 0.22782244162965615,
 0.9016145766629989,
 0.04615407289582629,
 0.8870216740449745,
 0.5622680783939463,
 0.9288600326401598]

In [3]: import numpy

In [4]: numpy.random.rand(5)
Out[4]: array([0.9288893 , 0.66600315, 0.82989425, 0.15717061, 0.33444802])

In [5]: list(numpy.random.rand(5))
Out[5]:
[0.46571036413626277,
 0.8268980751228664,
 0.9216520894106733,
 0.26706936577849916,
 0.47348417257319697]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the choices function from random and give it a `k` argument (number of values to choose):

```
>>> from random import choices
>>> choices(range(10), k=5)
[1, 8, 6, 9, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, numpy is the memory efficient and fastest way to work with arrays, especially when doing more complex things.

You can generate n random numbers [like so](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html)

```
import numpy as np

# how many random numbers you want 
n = 10

# create your array
array = np.random.rand(n)
```

You can also use a list comprehension to natively create lists, sets, dicts, etc in one beautiful Pythonic line. [See section 5.1.3 of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

This is often the go to thing and you will be using these a lot.

For your example we can also use Python’s built on random package

```
import random

# range here is a generator for values 0 to n-1
# array is created by a list comprehension
array = [random.random() for i in range(n)]
```